# Preview issues when i using a usb camera in android, a very high cpu usage

Tags: android, camera, usb, android-camera

It's a smart tvbox,  1.2GHz dual Cortex-A9 cpu, running Android 4.2.2. I'm using a USB Camera,when i'm run a camera demo, do nothing just preview, configure to 640x480, other params use default,and cpu usage is very high, if i use the default size 1280x720, the cpu usage is about 20%, strange, anyone knows? thks.

this is 640x480 adb shell top shows:

```
User 30%, System 44%, IOW 0%, IRQ 1%
User 178 + Nice 0 + Sys 259 + Idle 133 + IOW 0 + IRQ 0 + SIRQ 8 = 578

PID PR CPU% S  #THR     VSS     RSS PCY UID      Name
1762  1  19% S    20 133892K  24484K  fg media    /system/bin/mediaserver
1764  1  19% S    13  82036K  11712K  fg system   /system/bin/surfaceflinger
958   0   8% S    49 175308K  14360K     root     /vendor/bin/ampservice
```

Comment: why do you think this is more than normal CPU usage for this situation?

Comment: i found out the same issue in another soc, dual core cotex-a7 chip, when i using usb camera, it's cpu usage is more than 50% in 640x480@25fps,but when i use the internal cmos camera with csi interface, the cpu usage is about 15%, all this is tested when no other applications running. just different camera.

Comment: I am confused. For default 1280x720 preview you use the same usb camera, as 640x480, or these are different cameras?

Comment: tkx, alex. yep, same usb camera, all the same conditions but preview size, one is 1280x720,one is 640x480. recently i using the preview callback to calculate the preview fps, and i found out that when i using 640x480, it has almost 30 fps, and when i using 1280x720, is only has about 10 fps, i set the preview params as the same 25 fps, so i think that when 1280x720 has low cpu usage is because of the low fps.

Comment: I am not surprised that a usb camera ignores your framerate settings